# req_params_id is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I have several anchor tags in my Jade View which have the unique href value for all, I am generating anchor tags from the retrieved data from `mongodb` using `foreach`, for each anchor tag I'm inserting id after `processinreq/` as `#{item._id}`

Here is my Code in Jade:

```
!!! 5
html
    head
    title= title
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    link(href='/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet', media='screen')
    script.(src='js/jquery.js')
    script.(src='js/bootstrap.min.js')
    style.(type='text/css')
        tr {border:1px solid grey;}
        td {border:1px solid grey;}
body
    .container
        h1 View Requests Page
        p #{email}
        table
            tbody
                - if(raw.length)
                    each item in raw
                        tr
                            td
                                a(href='/processinreq/#{item._id}', id="idanch") #{item._id}
                            td 
                                a(href='/processinreq/#{item._id}', id="rqstanch") #{item.request}
                            td
                                a(href='/processinreq/#{item._id}', id="descanch") #{item.description}
```

and in my `routes.js` file, I'm trying to receive the `href` like this

```
app.post('/processinreq/:req_id', function(req, res) {
    var req_id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req_id);

    Requests.find({ 'id':req.user.id }, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {}
        res.render('inreq', { user:req.user, raw:data, requestedid:req_id });
    }); 
 });
```

But `console.log(req_id)` is displaying as `undefined`. How can I pass the `req_id` variable to `inreq` Jade view which I'm rendering by `res.render` above. I passed the `req_id` variable, but in Jade if i use it, the value is displaying for requestedid i.e #{requestedid} in Jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specified a token in the route as `:req_id`, express will add a field called `req_id` on to the params object.

I think changing your variable assignment to the following should fix the problem.

```
var req_id= req.params.req_id;
```

Have a look at the expressjs documentation on routing and params: http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.param

Express' documentation is stellar and super simple.

Check out my series of full stack JavaScript screencasts at http://tagtree.tv.